# Physical meaning of Berry phase

Tags: berry-pancharatnam-phase

The Berry phase is defined as the phase acquired by the wave function of an electron when passing along some closed contour along the Brillouin zone.
In the case of topological materials and, in particular, Dirac semimetals, it is equal to $\pi$ , when an electron bypasses the Dirac point.
But what physically means that the electron acquires the Berry phase. What will happen to an electron that acquires this phase? I would like to know more physical qualitative explanation than mathematical

Comment: This is one of those things that requires a much more in-depth introduction than you can expect to fit in a long post here. There is a whole storyline, akin to statistical thermodynamics.

Comment: I recommend you to read some reviews.